# Location to put credentials file for AWS PHP SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I created an EC2 Ubuntu instance.

The following is working using the AWS 2.6 SDK for PHP:

```
$client = DynamoDbClient::factory(array(
    'key' => 'xxx',
    'secret' => 'xxx',
    'region'  => 'eu-west-1'
));
```

I created a credentials file in `~/.aws/credentials`.
I put this in `/home/ubuntu/.aws/credentials`

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id=xxx
aws_secret_access_key=xxx
```

Trying the following does not work and gives an `InstanceProfileCredentialsException`  :

```
$client = DynamoDbClient::factory(array(
    'profile' => 'default',
    'region'  => 'eu-west-1'
));
```

There is a user `www-data` and a user `ubuntu`.
In what folder should I put the credentials file?

Comment: at my side this is working perfectly.
    $client = DynamoDbClient::factory(array('key'=>'keystring','secret'=>'sercretkeysting','region' => Region::US_EAST_1 #replace with your desired region));

try this format for access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a non-EC2 server that accesses SQS and needs credentials. I can't use `envvars` because there are various people with differing rights who run on this server and `envvars` is global.  For the same reason I don't think I can use an [AWS credential file](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/guide/latest/credentials.html#credential-profiles) stored under a user's home (although I also couldn't figure out how to make that work for user www-data.)

What I have done is set up a small file AWS_Creds.php

```
<?php
define ("AWS_KEY", "MY KEY HERE");
define ("AWS_SECRET", "MY SECRET");
?>
```

The file is stored outside of the webroot and included with `include ('ABSOLUTEPATH/AWS_Creds.php')` and I include the hard wired reference to the client factory.

Elegant? No.  Done? Yes.

**EDIT**

I forgot to mention: I [gitignore](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) AWS_Creds.php so that it doesn't go into our repo.

Comment: It does get it done, and I would only favor a solution that keeps the keys (no matter how IAM policy-restricted) out of a Git repo.

Answer (score 9):

One solution to set the credentials is:

`sudo nano /etc/apache2/envvars`

add environment variables:

```
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="xxx"
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="xxx"
```

`sudo service apache2 restart`

After that the following works:

```
$client = DynamoDbClient::factory(array(
    'region'  => 'eu-west-1'
));
```

Comment: I worked for making a script run on a local Ubuntu machine

Answer (score 6):

This is way too late, but the solution I found for shared servers where you can't actually use environment vars is to define a custom ini file location, like this:

```
require (__DIR__.'/AWSSDK/aws-autoloader.php');

use Aws\Credentials\CredentialProvider;
use Aws\S3\S3Client;

$profile = 'default';
$path = '/path/to/credentials';

$provider = CredentialProvider::ini($profile, $path);
$provider = CredentialProvider::memoize($provider);

$client = new \Aws\S3\S3Client([
    'version' => 'latest',
    'region' => 'us-west-2',
    'credentials' => $provider
]);
```

Note that you could even define different profiles with this method. 
Documentation [HERE](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/guide/guide/credentials.html)

Answer (score 5):

If you are calling the API from an EC2 instance, you should use [IAM roles](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/guide/latest/credentials.html).

> Using IAM roles is the preferred technique for providing credentials
>   to applications running on Amazon EC2. IAM roles remove the need to
>   worry about credential management from your application. They allow an
>   instance to "assume" a role by retrieving temporary credentials from
>   the EC2 instance's metadata server. These temporary credentials, often
>   referred to as instance profile credentials, allow access to the
>   actions and resources that the role's policy allows.

Answer (score 2):

basicly you can use like this :

```
$client = DynamoDbClient::factory(array(
    'key' => 'aws_key',
    'secret' => 'aws_secret',
    'region'  => 'us-east-1' 
));
```

but in documentation :

*Starting with the AWS SDK for PHP version 2.6.2, you can use an AWS credentials file to specify your credentials. This is a special, INI-formatted file stored under your HOME directory, and is a good way to manage credentials for your development environment. The file should be placed at ~/.aws/credentials, where ~ represents your HOME directory.*

and usage :

```
    $dynamoDbClient = DynamoDbClient::factory(array(
    'profile' => 'project1',
    'region'  => 'us-west-2',
));
```

more info : http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/guide/latest/credentials.html

Answer (score 1):

After watch the source code Credential.php in aws/aws-sdk-php/src,
php can not directly access /root folder in default. You can write $_SERVER['HOME']=[your new home path] in your php, and put the credential file in newHomePath/.aws/credentials.

Comment: $_SERVER['HOME'] was not set at all in my installation

Answer (score 0):

```
require('vendor/autoload.php');

use Aws\Ec2\Ec2Client;
```

> $credentials = new Aws\Credentials\Credentials('Your Access Key',
> 'Your Secret Key'); // **Place here both key**

```
$ec2Client = new Aws\Ec2\Ec2Client([
    'version' => 'latest',
    'region'  => 'ap-south-1',
    'credentials' => $credentials
]);

$result = $ec2Client->describeKeyPairs();

echo '<pre>';
print_r($result);
```

Reference site : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/guide/credentials.html#passing-credentials-into-a-client-factory-method